# Could performance issue occure for manyTomany?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, orm

I have such code

```
   public Serializable save(Product product) {
    product.getCategories().forEach(category -> category.getProducts().add(product));

    return super.save(product);
   }
```

Category will have many products, does hibernate load them all?

If yes, how to fix this issue on dao or entity level?

```
@Table//...
public class Product {//...
@Cascade(value = SAVE_UPDATE)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Category.class)
private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
```

}

```
@Table//...
public class Category {//... 
@Cascade(value = SAVE_UPDATE)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "productToCategory",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "productId")})
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer on my question:

[post](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/hibernate-mapped-collections.html)